# Ubuntu won't boot after clean install

Tags: boot, grub2, mbr

I did a fresh install of Ubuntu, upon restart my pc would say to enter a proper boot medium and press any key (or something similar to that)

I followed the instructions from looking at forums to generate this url...
http://paste.ubuntu.com/12628154

This is apparently the problem...
 => No boot loader is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda.

I have tried Rescatux and Super Grub2 but I do not know how to fix my MBR.  I installed Ubuntu stand alone, I don't have any other OS on this PC.  What do I need to do so that my computer will simply start up and load Ubuntu?

Thanks in advance.

~glen

Answer (score 0):

The easiest method I've ever found is to boot into a live Ubuntu disk and then install Boot-Repair and run it using the default settings. It's been much more reliable for me than either Rescatux or Super Grub 2 Disk.

[This link](http://www.howtogeek.com/114884/how-to-repair-grub2-when-ubuntu-wont-boot/) includes the repo for Boot Repair.

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me that booting in UEFI mode wouldn't work, so I had to switch to Legacy mode (via BIOS at bootscreen) and everything worked perfect this time.
Kubuntu works fine en UEFI mode, it's just me that I couldn't come with a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

To reinstall GRUB bootloader to your Ubuntu installation  in **EFI mode** –

Boot from the Ubuntu install media, then  open a terminal and execute:

```
sudo mount /dev/sda2 /mnt
sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/boot/efi
for i in /dev /dev/pts /proc /sys /run; do sudo mount -B $i /mnt$i; done
sudo chroot /mnt
grub-install /dev/sda
update-grub
```

Note :

`sda` = disk | `sda1` = efi partition | `sda2` = system partition (taken from your pastebin output)

I recommend to not use any 3rd party tools as they may bring along issues some time later on!